# Jackson - allow leading zeroes and keep them

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following Java bean:

```
public class Something {

    @NotBlank
    private final String value;

    @JsonCreator
    public Something(@JsonProperty("value")final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, o);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
    }
}
```

And the following utility class to handle json serializing and deserializing

```
public class JsonUtils {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Inject
    public JsonUtils(final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public <T> T jsonToObject(final String jsonString, final Class<T> classType) {

        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, classType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new JsonException(ErrorMessage.ERROR_PARSE_JSON_TO_OBJECT, e);
        }
    }

    public <V> String objectToJson(final V objectToBeParsed) {

        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objectToBeParsed);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new JsonException(ErrorMessage.ERROR_PARSE_OBJECT_TO_JSON, e);
        }
    }
}
```

My object mapper gets configured here

```
public class ParserModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Provides
    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {

        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.disable(WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        objectMapper.enable(ALLOW_NUMERIC_LEADING_ZEROS);

        objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
        objectMapper.registerModule(getSerializersModule());
        objectMapper.registerModule(getDeserializerModule());

        return objectMapper;
    }

    private SimpleModule getSerializersModule() {

        final SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        simpleModule.addSerializer(Something.class, new SomethingSerializer());

        return simpleModule;
    }

    private SimpleModule getDeserializerModule() {

        final SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        simpleModule.addDeserializer(Something.class, new SomethingDeserializer());

        return simpleModule;
    }
}
```

This JSON object in the end will be the returned value in the response body of a REST API, but the spec of the API expects a raw string with only the value of the "value" field. So, if my Something has the value `"hello world"`, it should return `hello world` in the response body, and not `{"value":"hello world"}`.

This spec wasn't defined by me, I'm required to abide by it, and there is no way it will change.

So I created the following serializer and deserializer which are registered in the object mapper as seen earlier

```
public class SomethingSerializer extends StdSerializer<Something> {

    public SomethingSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public SomethingSerializer(final Class<Something> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(final Something something, final JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, final SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeRawValue(something.getValue());
    }
}

public class SomethingDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Something> {

    public SomethingDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public SomethingDeserializer(final Class<?> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public Something deserialize(final JsonParser jsonParser, final DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        return new Something(jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser).toString());
    }
}
```

Now the actual value I have in my something object isn't `"hello world"` but rather a string that looks like this: `01.something.this.that.org`. Notice the leading zero here.

So, whenever I try to deserialize an object like that:

```
Something result = jsonUtils.jsonToObject(response.getBody(), Something.class);
```

I get an exception:

```
JsonParseException: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed
 at [Source: (String)"01.something.this.that.org"; line: 1, column: 2]
```

After looking into this exception in Jackson's source I found out there's a feature that allows me to "skip" this exception, and I thought I had found my solution, so I added this in my object mapper:

```
objectMapper.enable(ALLOW_NUMERIC_LEADING_ZEROS);
```

And now I don't get the exception anymore, cool. But the deserialized string becomes: `1.something.this.that.org`. So here I am, back to square one.

Is there any way I can:
1) not get an exception on the leading zeroes
2) actually keep the leading zeroes

Thanks.

Edit:

Actually after adding the feature to allow leading zeroes, my first test was to only parse a value of `01` which returned `1`, but if I try to parse the sample string I have given here, I get another exception:

```
JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('s') in numeric value: Decimal point not followed by a digit at [Source: (String)"01.something.this.that.org"; line: 1, column: 5]
```

So I guess my question really is, how can I have Jackson interpret the raw string as an actual String, since right now it seems to be interpreting it as a number.

Comment: Very strange! Why are you shoehorning Jackson to both serialize and deserialize something that isn’t JSON?

Comment: in some cases (in case of errors for example), the API will return actual proper json strings, otherwise I would indeed just treat it as plain text